# reactiveValues from server.R to global.R in shiny R

Tags: r, global, shiny

I am defining my variables (`sdate` and `edate`) as reactive values  in global.R

global.R

```
sdate = reactiveValues()    
edate=reactiveValues()   
print(sdate)  
print(edate)
```

I am getting start and end dates in server.R

```
output$daterange <- renderPrint({  
        assign('sdate', input$daterange[1], envir=.GlobalEnv)  
        assign('edate', input$daterange[2], envir=.GlobalEnv)  
        return(input$daterange)
      })
```

I would like to use `sdate` and `edate` back in global.R to filter my data

```
df[df$Date>=sdate & df$Date<=edate,]
```

The error I am getting is

> Error in NextMethod(.Generic) :    (list) object cannot be coerced to
>   type 'double'

Comment: It seems strange that you would use start and end dates chosen inside of a session, and assign that back to globals (meaning all other sessions would be affected as well)--was that your intention?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Joe's comment: you should ony use `global.R` to store some data and some functions, not to process something.
About your error message, a `reactivevalues` object can be converted to an ordinary `list` object with the `reactiveValuesToList()` function.

Comment: Thanks, now I am processing the selection inside server.R